# Why did I receive wrong location notifications?

Tags: android, google-play, android-location

I use Google's `LocationClient.requestLocationUpdates` to receive GPS location notifications.
I have a service that runs in the background, and every now and then, asks for location notifications.

It usually works as expected, but, to my amazement, sometimes I receive the same location notification again and again. 
Once I had received a location notification that was 30km away from where I actually was! It was where I was a hour ago!
BTW - on that occasion, the geofence mechanism did not work as well.

So - something fundamentally is wrong here.
Maybe it's better not to use Google play?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there wasn't sufficient GPS Signal.

Comment: I don't understand. what do u mean? I receive Location object in onLocationChanged, so how can I know about the quality of the GPS signal?

Comment: You would only be using GetLastKnownLocation to get the location. There might not be sufficient signal (Signal would be week and take time to refresh the coordinates) and hence the last known location value would still be returned.

Comment: I do not use GetLastKnownLocation, as accuracy is critical. But when I get notify about a location - how could it be inaccurate?